# Почему "скатертью дорога" прозвучало как обида?

Tags: этикет, фразеология

Пожелала другу счастливого пути фразой: "Скатертью дорога", а друг страшно обиделся на меня. Что я плохого сказала? Что может быть лучше чище и ровнее, чем скатерть на праздничном столе?

Answer (score 4):

Исторически всё верно, первоначальный смысл поговорки - именно, пожелание доброго пути, по ровной как скатерть дороге.

Однако в нынешнее время, значение фразеологизма изменилось, и теперь он означает "проваливай, и без тебя обойдёмся". Ничего удивительного, что ваш друг обиделся на такое "напутствие".

В связи с выявленным расхождением в понимании данного выражения, добавляю ссылки на словари:
[Словарь русских синонимов](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/162963/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E)
[Большой словарь русских поговорок](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/42398/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E)
[Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка](http://phraseology.academic.ru/3730/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0)
[Ожегов, Шведова](http://www.slovopedia.com/4/209/672156.html)
[Викисловарь](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0)

Comment: Пожелание "скатертью дорога" произносится в ответ на угрозу уйти и не возвращаться. "Да пожалуйста, скатертью дорожка, плакать не будем!"

Comment: @grumant, необязательно. 
 *Хотите заниматься у меня дальше, слушайтесь Филина. Не хотите — скатертью дорога. Цацкаться с вами больше не собираемся* (М. Ромм. Рычаг Архимеда).

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Кроме разве того, что стали употреблять чаще.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Кроме разве того, что стали употреблять чаще.

>В связи с выявленным расхождением в понимании данного выражения, добавляю ссылки на словари:  

Можно узнать, у кого с кем расхождения - и что доказывают Ваши ссылки?

Comment: @behemothus, например, с вами. Если вы потрудитесь пройти по этим ссылкам и прочитать содержание словарных статей, то нигде не встретите упоминания доброго пути как возможного значения в современном языке. Найдёте правда в Ожегова, Шведовой как первоначальное значение выражения.

Comment: Спасибо, я обычно сначала читаю, потом спрашиваю.
В чем конкретно Вы увидели расхождение со мной, я могу узнать?

Comment: > Ничего не изменилось. Кроме разве
> того, что стали употреблять чаще.

Ну, и минус моему ответу. И извините, но в ближайшее время, отвечать на ваши комментарии и комментировать ваши высказывания не буду.

Comment: Не смею препятствовать. Тем более что разговора все равно не получается. 
На всякий случай ссылка на употребление в Нацкорпусе:

http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%EA%E0%F2%E5%F0%F2%FC%FE%20%E4%EE%F0%EE%E3%E0&p=0

Comment: @behemothus, спасибо за ссылку. Последнее употребление в литературе со значением пожелание доброго пути, по нацкорпусу, 1941 год (32). Причём там у А. Н. Толстого как раз обыгрывается изменение смысла выражения. Есть ещё воспоминание о том как комсомольцы Ставангера в конце 20-х использовали выражение в старом значении, что уже тогда воспринималось неоднозначно(14). И сетование Н. В. Богословского на изменение восприятия фразеологизма. Все остальные примеры употребления в устаревшем значении относятся к XIX веку (48, 49, 51, 52 и далее). Это как раз то, что я и утверждаю в своём ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Если я не ошибаюсь, подобное явление, когда два слова или выражения могут иметь противоположные значения, называется энантиосемия. При этом в случаях со словами (просмотреть или прослушать) это объясняется омонимией морфем, то у выражений смысл меняется из-за употребления в ироническом смысле.

Comment: Да. Но вопрос-то, насколько понимаю, не совсем даже в том, как это назвать и есть ли она тут, а в том, имеет ли место изменение значение с пожелания *хорошей* дороги на пожелание *плохой* (вот тогда бы это была действительно энантиосемия). Я такого не вижу и поэтому никакой энантиосемии не наблюдаю. Исхожу, опять же, из того, как поставлен вопрос, а не из того, что можно еще подумать и сказать по поводу самого выражения.

Comment: Мне представляется, что всё зависит от конкретной ситуации и интонации, с которой была сказана фраза. В данном случае речь, конечно, о пожелании хорошей дороги. Но мне чисто теоретически представима ситуация, когда собеседник может произнести эту фразу со злом, а вовсе не как доброе пожелание. Получается, что энантиосемия есть. Вроде бы...

Comment: Энантиосемия, тут всё-таки не наблюдается. Старое значение - это нейтральное пожелание доброго пути, современное - негативное, по отношению к собеседнику, пожелание быстрейшего удаления от говорящего. Т.е. изменилась лишь эмоциональная окраска выражения, а не сам смысл.

Answer (score 1):

Все течет, все меняется, слова и выражения за столетия обрастают новыми смыслами, оттенками, интонациями. И ведь суть-то не очень изменилась, в обоих случаях это пожелание РОВНОЙ дороги, но появилась явная коннотация, что по ровной дороге поскорей бы убирался ты отсюда.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что Ваш друг не прав. Да, часто подобное выражение в отдельно взятых устах означает что-то типа "Ну и катись", но это не стоит возводить в абсолют. Всё зависит от контекста и от интонации, с которым этой произнесено.

Заметьте, ведь даже в негативном контексте пожелание не означает какой-то плохой дороги. Максимум - ехать дальше и быстрее. Так что никак не могу согласиться с оценкой "значение изменилось".

Если во всем видеть что-то плохое, можно и на "ни пуха, ни пера" обидеться.

===========================
**Марк Из**

> Вопрос был не в том, изменило выражение значение до антонима или нет, а в том, почему обиделся.

Ну это тоже исключительно Ваша трактовка. Несмотря на заголовок, текст вопросах не оставляет сомнений в том, что автору интересно именно изменение значения (в словарном понимании) этого выражения.
Впрочем, могу ответить. Обиделся потому, что неверно оценил доброе пожелание. Тоже спорить не о чем. Только какое это отношение к русскому языку имеет?

Это уже что-то из области коммуникативного этикета (вот, кстати, сообразил, как назвать то, что здесь обозвано "значением".

Давайте от печки. Это фразеологизим? Да, надеюсь Вы не будете отрицать. Открываем любой словарь фразеологизмов. Смотри, о чем сообщают после слов "значение фразологизма". Убеждаемся, что в первую очередь идет о происхождении. 
Если говорят об особенностях его употребления (как в моих примерах), то в самом конце.

А! Загововок-то, оказыватся, не от автора. Спасибо, Ларf научила историю изменений смотреть. Тогда вообще и говорить не о чем. Никаких "почему обиделся" там и не было.
Вопрос именно о самом выражении, обида - как повод. Я так понимаю.

Comment: >Последнее употребление в литературе...  
  
К сожалению, это только Ваша оценка. Я не могу подобно Вам решать за авторов, что имеется в виду, по отрывочному контексту.   
Тем более не могу согласиться с Вашим пониманием Толстого. Ничего там не "обыгрывается". Хотя, возможно, Вы и это слово употребляете в каком-то особом понимании. Там речь о том, что один из двух собеседников не понимает и не принимает "нового" значения.

Меня другое забавляет. Вы столь активно комментируете "чужие" ссылки и при этом обычно отказываетесь разъяснять свои - что именно Вы там увидели - и почему.

Comment: Рощин новое значение принимает. В полном виде диалог выглядит так:

*- Эвакуируетесь в Германию? - спросил Рощин.  
- Да…   
- Ну, что ж, по-русски говорится: скатертью дорога.  
- Я неплохо изучил русский язык, я знаю, - когда говорят: "Скатертью дорога", это значит: "убирайся ко всем чертям"  
- А хотя бы и так...*

Т.е. Толстой с помощью разности значений фразеологизма показал, что герой с одной стороны, как минимум вежлив, а с другой - как он относится к эвакуирующемуся. Это я и называю "обыграл" (см. значение 2. в БТС)

И да, в ряде отрывках значение не ясно, но это не отменят остальных.

Comment: Простите, Вы опять спорите с Вами же выдуманными химерами. Это чтобы не употреблять слова "троллинг".  
Давайте конкретнее уже. Что именно доказывает и чего не отменяет?  
Что Вы так упрямо доказываете - и зачем? В рамках заявленного вопроса, желательно.

Comment: Я доказываю, что в современном языке фразеологизм "скатертью дорога", по умолчанию, означает негативное отношение к собеседнику.

Не отменяет сообщений, где из контекста отношение к собеседнику видно.

А в рамках заявленного вопроса, вы привели лишь ссылку на нацкорпус, которую сами же не принимаете во внимание и собственное мнение, что ничего не изменилось, даже без намёка на доказательства.

Comment: >по умолчанию, означает негативное отношение к собеседнику.  
  
Вам оно надо?  
  
Я, следуя постановке вопроса, показываю, что выражение не изменило **значения**, т.е. никак не означает **плохой** дороги. Так о чем спор-то тогда?  
  
То, что вы говорите, не есть семантическая категория (как бы не называли), а некое ироническое употребление (не знаю даже как толком назвать), о чем, кстати, и говорит герой Толстого. Впрочем, даже это понимание вполне можно оспорить, но это уже в другой раз. 
 
http://frazbook.ru/2009/01/15/skatertyu-doroga/
http://frazbook.ru/2011/10/07/skatertyu-doroga-2/

Comment: Вопрос был не в том, изменило выражение значение до антонима или нет, а в том, почему обиделся. Обиделся, потому что это выражение имеет сейчас негативную окраску. Раньше оно этой окраски не имело, соответственно и значение всё-таки изменилось. Тоже самое пишут и по обеим вашим ссылкам. "Катись отсюда", тоже плохой дороги не желает, но синонимом доброго пути тем не менее не является.

Answer (score 0):

"Скатертью, скатертью дальний путь стелется..."(с)

"Скатертью дорожка" (с).

Слова-то правильные! Изначально добрые. Волшебное :) пожелание.

А вот какие настоящие эмоции у произносящего это пожелание и с какой интонацией он это говорит? Вот в чём дело. Ну, так тогда любая фраза может иметь двойной смысл.

ИМХО, даже если эти слова говорят в не совсем ;) добром расположении духа - это доброе пожелание. Оно как бы "гасит" агрессию говорящего. Вот, мол, как бы я к тебе не относился, я всё ж таки желаю тебе доброго пути. И чего тут обидного?

Comment: ИМХО, :), ;), - вместо тире, ? в конце ответа...